# Couldnt find class memcached

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, memcached, xampp

I have been trying to install memcached on an ubuntu server and I followed a lot of tutorials over the internet. I am using 32-bit ubuntu 12.04, php version 5.4.7, xampp server 1.8.1 which are all 32-bit versions. In the end, I followed the tutorial in the below link and I installed all the things listed with no error. 
http://stevelove.org/2009/09/30/how-to-install-php-memcached-on-an-ubuntu-server/

The only problem I have is that when I installed memcached using "sudo pecl install memcached" command, the extension couldn't be added to php.ini file. Then I used phpinfo() to learn which php.ini file I am using and added extension=memcached.so to the ini file. When I restarted xampp server, php.ini file doesn't work and it tries to download the pages. In the php error log, I get this error.

[30-May-2013 16:42:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcache.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Since I couldn't enable the extension, even though memcached is listed as installed with php -m command, I get Class memcached not found error when I try to execute my php code.
Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you installed the server but not the extension, try

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
```

ps: memcache != memcached

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you for your answer Mohammad. I know that memcache is not memcached and as I said, when I list modules, memcached seems installed (not memcache) but when I use phpinfo(), memcached is not listed.

It turns out that even though I installed memcached, problem was xampp installation. I removed lampp and php5 installed in ubuntu and purged everything I installed. Then I installed xampp with development packages and re-installed libmemcached etc. It works fine now.

If there is anybody having similar problem, I can explain in detail.